# Turning on whole program optimization in some static library increases dramatically the library size !

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, optimization, protocol-buffers

In Visual Studio 2010, I have a C/C++ static library project. When I turn on the option **whole program optimization** in **release** mode, I obtain a .lib file exceeding 90 MB !
When I turn off this option the size is reduced to 24 MB.
This library contains hundreds of classes generated with proto-buffer.

I'm wondering why this option increases the size ?
Under which conditions we must turn it off ?

*Edit : Changed MO to MB thanks chrisaycock*

Comment: MO = Mega Octet, I see no problem with that.

Comment: Considering the answers given, try linking the library to an executable that uses a number of the classes;  You will find that the size of the library file makes little or no difference to the size of the executable.  The library contains information to allow optimisation at link time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Whole program optimization means things are not optimized until the link stage.

The size of a static library is not the thing to look at. When in this mode, the static library may be full of extra information needed for the final optimization/link stage. If you weren't doing whole program optimization then that information could have be thrown away after the static library was built, but when you are that information has to be kept until the end.

Look at the size of the final executable instead. (It may still increase, but it shouldn't increase by such a huge amount.)

Answer (score 8):

> I'm wondering why this option
>   increases the size?

Because you are building a static library, not an executable. **Whole Program Optimization** leaves a lot of the optimization until *link time* (rather than at *compile time*). Thus, your library contains unoptimized "intermediate representation" rather than assembly code.

> Under which conditions we must turn it
>   off?

For static libraries, as you've just discovered.

Comment: I see no reason to disable optimization for static libs. Their size doesn't matter much.

Comment: @Athari It's not a size issue; it's a compatibility one. See the last paragraph in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/24/quick-tips-on-using-whole-program-optimization.aspx

Comment: The article is talking about static libs you intend ship to others who may link them to their projects using a different compiler version. Turning off WPO in that case makes sense for compatibility reasons, but if the libs are only for internal use, with the same compiler version, then WPO should be fine and can be beneficial. (If it wasn't, I doubt the option would exist at all for static libs.)

Answer (score 4):

Enabling whole program optimization lets linker to inline functions defined in implementation (*.cpp) files. Inlining the same function in many places can increase binary size significantly.